# Форма обратной связи

Tags: apache, php

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь добавить форму обратной связи на сайт, который тестирую на ПК. Установил апаче, тестовый файл php работает. А php скрипт обработки формы браузер открывает как его внутреннее содержимое - сам текст скрипта. Попробовал много вариантов - все то же.Неправильные скрипты или я в чем-то ошибаюсь? Может кто поделится действительно рабочим скриптом про обработку формы и тем, (что очень важно!) как его добавить?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы скрипт на PHP исполнялся, нужно к апачу прикрепить см php.exe

Чтобы не гемороиться скачай пакет DENWER или XAMPP и туда свой файл на php и проверяй.

ps около ответа есть галочка.